# How can I detect the cell value changed of a specific datagridview column? - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I want to detect the cell value has been changed of a specific column.

My Datagridview name is `DGV_Products` and it has 6 columns.

```
Product ID | Descriptions | Quantity | Unit Price | Discount | Amount
G 01       |  Gallon #01  |    2     |   1850     |    100   |  3600 
G 02       |  Gallon #02  |    1     |   1850     |    50    |  1800
```

I want to fire some code only when the `Quantity column` cell value changed not when the `discount column` value change. How can I fulfill my task? Currently the codes, what I have tried which is;

```
 Private Sub DGV_Products_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_Products.CellValueChanged

    If DGV_Products.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        Dim Quantity As Integer = CInt(DGV_Products.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value)
        Dim UnitProce As Integer = CInt(DGV_Products.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value)
        Dim DiscountPrice As Integer = CInt(DGV_Products.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value)

        Dim TotalDiscount As Integer = DiscountPrice * Quantity
        Dim Amount As Integer = UnitProce * Quantity
        Amount = Amount - TotalDiscount

        DGV_Products.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = TotalDiscount
        DGV_Products.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value = Amount


        RefreshTotal()

    End If
End Sub
```

*Apologies for bad english.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh, I got the the solution.
I use `e.ColumnIndex` property and my problem has solved.

```
 If DGV_Products.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
            Dim Quantity As Integer = CInt(DGV_Products.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value)
            Dim UnitPrice As Integer = CInt(DGV_Products.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value)
            Dim UnitDisocunt As Integer = GetDiscountByProductID(DGV_Products.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value)
            Dim TotalDiscount As Integer = UnitDisocunt * Quantity
            DGV_Products.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value = TotalDiscount
            Dim Ammount As Integer = UnitPrice * Quantity
            Ammount = Ammount - TotalDiscount
            DGV_Products.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Value = Ammount
            RefreshTotal()
        End If

    End If
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
if (Visible && !(e.ColumnIndex == 0))
{
    phoneEdited = true;
    MessageBox.Show("A Phone entry has been entered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub dataGrid_CellBeginEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dataGrid.CellBeginEdit
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Detected First Column")
    End If
End Sub
```